# Unknown column [name] in 'where clause' MYSQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have came across a problem and I can't work a way round it.

```
 $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT g.id AS gig_id, g.sname AS gig_name, g.start AS start FROM gig AS g
        WHERE (`sname` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

This currently works, but I am in the process of adding a join(which is not important just now).

When I try switching 'sname' in the clause

```
(`sname` LIKE '%".$query."%')
```

with g.sname or gig_name

I get the error unknown column 'g.sname'[or gig_name] in 'where clause'.

Anyway to get a workaround w/o changing my php?

This code is used for a search function on a php webpage.

Edit: What I am trying to get working

```
        $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT g.id AS gig_id, g.sname AS gig_name, g.start AS start, v.sname AS venue_name FROM gig AS g, venue as v
        WHERE g.venue=v.id AND (`gig_name` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Edit: I must add that the column name in the table is 'sname' from gig, but I will be adding another table which has duplicate column names hence the reason to use the AS statement.

Comment: show the join query u are using since g.sname should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, you need to use g.sname in the where clause

```
$raw_results = mysql_query(
"SELECT 
g.id AS gig_id,
g.sname AS gig_name, 
g.start AS start, 
v.sname AS venue_name 
FROM gig g
inner join  
venue  v on v.id = g.venue 
WHERE 
`g`.`sname` LIKE '%".$query."%'"
) or die(mysql_error());
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4960ac/1)

Comment: Spot on, much appreciated!